# Store the login details in session in laravel

Tags: laravel

I have a function in controller checklogin() which checks the user details. I want to store into session. So I can get the name of the user and display in blade view

**Controller**

```
public function checklogin(Request $request)
    {

        $req=$request->validate([
                    'name'=>'required',
                    'email'=>'required|email',
                    'password'=>'required|regex:/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[@_!]){8,}/'

                    ]);
        $userdata = array(
          'name' => $request->input('name') ,
          'email'=>$request->input('email'),
          'password' => $request->input('password')
        );
        if (Auth::attempt($userdata))
        {
             
            $data = $request->session()->put('user',$userdata['name']); 
             dd($data) ; //returning null 
            
             return redirect('/home');
        }
        else
        {   
            
            return back()->with('error', 'Wrong Login Details');
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to store logged in user detail in session.You can call auth helper function which will return auth instance.

```
{{auth()->user()->name}}
```

if you have both logged in or guest page same then you can do null check

```
 {{ auth()->user()!=null?auth()->user()->name:null }}
```